# Can't find a way to decrypt a JWT token generated from a ASP.net app in Python

Tags: python, rest, encryption, jwt

I have been trying to decrypt a JTW Token that is generated in ASP.net by using the code below

```
public string GenerateJwtToken(ICollection<Claim> claims)
    {
        var signingKey =
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Identity:Jwt:SigningKey"]));
        var encryptionKey =
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Identity:Jwt:EncryptionKey"]));

        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);
        var expires = _systemClock.UtcNow.DateTime.AddHours(24);
        var issueDateTime = _systemClock.UtcNow.DateTime;

        var encryptingCredentials = new EncryptingCredentials(
            encryptionKey,
            JwtConstants.DirectKeyUseAlg,
            SecurityAlgorithms.Aes256CbcHmacSha512);

        var securityToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateJwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["Identity:Jwt:Issuer"],
            _configuration["Identity:Jwt:Audience"],
            new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            issueDateTime,
            expires,
            issueDateTime,
            signingCredentials,
            encryptingCredentials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(securityToken);
    }
```

I am trying to decrypt it in Python.

I have tried using few libraries and the closest I got is with `jwcrypto` lib but now I am getting some error regarding `jwcrypto.jws.InvalidJWSSignature: Verification failed for all signatures["Failed: [InvalidJWSSignature('Verification failed')]"]`

Here is my Python code (Token :

```
from jwcrypto import jwt, jwk, jwe
import base64

s = "<Identity:Jwt:EncryptionKey>" # The same key that is used in the ASP.net app
base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(s.encode("utf-8"))
base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("utf-8")

# Convert the Base64 string to Base64Url
base64_string = base64_string.rstrip("=")
base64_string = base64_string.replace("+", "-")
base64_string = base64_string.replace("/", "_")

print(base64_string)

k = {"k": base64_string, "kty": "oct"}
key = jwk.JWK(**k)
token = "eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0..4C1FW4w2BZ6Nq5jzM1jbdQ.LJqaiSsaIxRgFw9vTs8zNhHH824JJyfU6Jmxi7hta8OyeUO11Df4HuFzC-3PyVrhI0lICtGqmY6BeaaQkquJIz65XgOi9sdR1tBNHkc5bKjTyoXxW65QbdaDhvjpFJXoe66eTPn32tf2M6VDU6w1hJitQgVpq8v11rUf2YqP0g-vkZbxTmD-Cd5BY6hHSuJ_CJ1SDIYzVGKw7mDudM0Opm9EeXEbtVZCL7YagziG_WSryfCaUh9OLulre4SOvZ8T5t5duADEn4MHiYRUZjNbXZIhsWsLfxhINhspekoS4ha8rYQSIHH8208TD4wckQ3zx70XYNHbQiqSr3Atlt-zXPIG1MsfXZJOrg4-KFeKaWxlMfyx3iPiSRisILQm-ATGDnRxHewEuU0gwLyHkwTsyObO7zIuDs82RMgCB5jFs-PK27YHPplv26w9WDQ1F88Lbiumxv9j1zvF6rTQEFte7OnHJD9BpxTDmC9vvUNbdsBLn2tlhAtWKU-oBUOtA-vJIiWz3lt_Mz5Xj1G9WlcHtcUNi-kv_ZFDz45gmG-nhvHDZE3Sp8qnyko8W6tmDusXI6nTwseQ3FrQgUCR69jJ_bEvGjGzqrJ2Pv0qFcyNuHZglB8CvX3kALoMeRyYuV_ULD0wEDd8QET-w_6gKj1-aPfGqcWbJO0JRxphWNJcVLcicoe3fWqyXrmv6iPWZsKcmEYE2T3qco3dVeoYgC-EkPBROfHXzvBdb9ABqfW2dc782fPHXhahZkJJNfXaxNC6Lc8COe-DjQVUtU-z-VL6erhmgzb-G178A074q3kX2b1nDp4zEMs4t704SEdSyo4uKzamKwXtbc_XwKb-Xcda_udoWhW1KiQkJktHhYnZ6g1dcUjQ0G5R9P8hX3T597mNJyHq8lVr6hYhWXRZZLm_1w.VL2-nxFdi3b3-lUy-Oi0sQOPTwgVmdIkLV9TLBYNYUs"
ET = jwt.JWT(key=key, jwt=token, expected_type="JWE")
print(ET.claims)
ST = jwt.JWT(key=key, jwt=ET.claims)
print(ST.claims)
```

But I can't seem to make it work, would be great if anyone can enlighten me on how I can decrypt the token.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that the C# library applied first signs the JWT (JWS) and then encrypts the signed JWT (JWE), which is why there are two keys, one for encryption and one for signing, see [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/json-web-encryption-jwe-in-dotnet-core).

The current Python code does not take this into account. Instead it uses the *same* key for decryption and verification, namely the encryption key. However, for verification the signing key must be used.

Example:

The following encrypted JWT:

```
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiY3R5IjoiSldUIn0..RUhT_5WjzRut6_SLvwkinA.OOx5ZuPyfGHzqA8MrR6AmzYkmv6EbgQsgoEBuWAFx85Ce03jMSjoNxgYSOVpdBmn73rc3d91N2J_GF71DzvMwq1F0Q9xcNML2_gB_39H61VDIMJJXfk7aRZvZUHZCIDzd6LvjAjqW5Q6zeT4YKkLk9thH1hjl9FRqqZb11UxKpRGXFNnZihzVP7_4BbhUoCT03k-YH2reG7Ss3JMktqlRnTqhsVltuBdXCs_jTQ7_fiJqMRc21NootxlhNIkum9aOv-003_whOB3UP7TK8L9iSxrO7sGBkSnh8dayS_iGxsrSEnfpd82HMVYF-1wMSfNsUi5-UH7OJZ9TjnXwolD5vBPB6OCZsSBmLVvHbkP4EA.DUHsU5XZu2RVvQ49EX5Tg4FADJq77eZPX9OhnyUgRrc
```

was created with the C# code using the encryption key

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
```

and the signing key

```
0123456789012345
```

as well as sample values for issuer, audience and subject.

It can be decrypted with JWCrypto as follows:

```py
from jwcrypto import jwt, jwk, jwe
import base64

# decryption
rawEncKey = b"0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123" 
encJWK = {"k": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(rawEncKey).decode(), "kty": "oct"}
encKey = jwk.JWK(**encJWK)
token = "eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIiwiY3R5IjoiSldUIn0..RUhT_5WjzRut6_SLvwkinA.OOx5ZuPyfGHzqA8MrR6AmzYkmv6EbgQsgoEBuWAFx85Ce03jMSjoNxgYSOVpdBmn73rc3d91N2J_GF71DzvMwq1F0Q9xcNML2_gB_39H61VDIMJJXfk7aRZvZUHZCIDzd6LvjAjqW5Q6zeT4YKkLk9thH1hjl9FRqqZb11UxKpRGXFNnZihzVP7_4BbhUoCT03k-YH2reG7Ss3JMktqlRnTqhsVltuBdXCs_jTQ7_fiJqMRc21NootxlhNIkum9aOv-003_whOB3UP7TK8L9iSxrO7sGBkSnh8dayS_iGxsrSEnfpd82HMVYF-1wMSfNsUi5-UH7OJZ9TjnXwolD5vBPB6OCZsSBmLVvHbkP4EA.DUHsU5XZu2RVvQ49EX5Tg4FADJq77eZPX9OhnyUgRrc"
ET = jwt.JWT(key=encKey, jwt=token, expected_type="JWE")
print("JWT:", ET.claims)

# verification
rawSigKey = b"0123456789012345" 
sigJWK = {"k": base64.urlsafe_b64encode(rawSigKey).decode(), "kty": "oct"}
sigKey = jwk.JWK(**sigJWK)
ST = jwt.JWT(key=sigKey, jwt=ET.claims)
print("payload:", ST.claims)
```

with the output:

```
JWT: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoic29tZV91c2VybmFtZSIsIm5iZiI6MTY3MjU5Njg1MywiZXhwIjoxNjcyNjgzMjUzLCJpYXQiOjE2NzI1OTY4NTMsImlzcyI6Imlzc3VlciIsImF1ZCI6ImF1ZGllbmNlIn0.KaweJITus79GvZwX-OF_7Yc1u2X6VNrv8tuCkpvjwa5yEI5MJPnY4u7T87Zxpw__KcD1-_pJYTPeQuycRUrAfg
payload: {"user":"some_username","nbf":1672596853,"exp":1672683253,"iat":1672596853,"iss":"issuer","aud":"audience"}
```